# Why when loading messages form the hard disk using MimeKit it's ver slow?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, email, mimekit

I understand when downloading the emails from the server it's slow.
But when running the program and reading/loading the messages from the hard disk is there any way to make it faster ?

In the constructor i start a background worker

```
DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(emailsDirectory);
            files = di.GetFiles();
            if (files.Length > 0)
            {
                backgroundWorker2.RunWorkerAsync();
            }
```

Then in the dowork event

```
private void backgroundWorker2_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            int counter = 0;
            MimekitallLoadedMessages = new List<MimeKit.MimeMessage>();
            MimeKit.MimeMessage loadedMessage = null;
            DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(emailsDirectory);
            FileInfo[] files = di.GetFiles();
            for (int i = 0; i < files.Length; i++)
            {
                string uid = seenUids[0];
                loadedMessage = MimeKit.MimeMessage.Load(files[i].FullName);
                MimekitallLoadedMessages.Add(loadedMessage);
                downloaded.Add(seenUids[i]);
                counter += 1;
                int nProgress = counter * 100 / files.Length;
                backgroundWorker2.ReportProgress(nProgress);
            }
        }
```

Then the progresschanged event where i update a progressBar pbt1 and a listView(ListViewCostumControl.lvnf)

```
private void backgroundWorker2_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            pbt1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
            pbt1.Text = e.ProgressPercentage.ToString() + "%";
            pbt1.Invalidate();
            ListViewCostumControl.lvnf.Items.Add(new ListViewItem(new string[]
            {
              MimekitallLoadedMessages[countUploadMsg].From.ToString(),         //From Column
              MimekitallLoadedMessages[countUploadMsg].Subject,                 //Subject Column
              MimekitallLoadedMessages[countUploadMsg].Date.ToString()      //Date Column
            }));
            countUploadMsg += 1;
        }
```

And this is the class part of the pbt1 maybe this make it slow ? Not sure

```
public class ProgressBarWithText : ProgressBar
        {
            const int WmPaint = 15;
            SizeF TextSize;
            PointF TextPos;
            bool dontpaint = false;

            public ProgressBarWithText()
            {
                this.DoubleBuffered = true;
                this.TextChanged += ProgressBarWithText_TextChanged;
                this.SizeChanged += ProgressBarWithText_SizeChanged;
            }

            public override string Text
            {
                get { return base.Text; }
                set { base.Text = value; }
            }

            void RecalcTextPos()
            {
                if (this.IsDisposed == true)
                    return;
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(base.Text))
                    return;

                using (var graphics = Graphics.FromHwnd(this.Handle))
                {
                    TextSize = graphics.MeasureString(base.Text, this.Font);
                    TextPos.X = (this.Width / 2) - (TextSize.Width / 2);
                    TextPos.Y = (this.Height / 2) - (TextSize.Height / 2);
                }
            }

            void ProgressBarWithText_SizeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                RecalcTextPos();
            }

            void ProgressBarWithText_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                RecalcTextPos();
            }

            protected override void WndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m)
            {
                base.WndProc(ref m);

                if (dontpaint == false)
                {
                    switch (m.Msg)
                    {
                        case WmPaint:
                            using (var graphics = Graphics.FromHwnd(Handle))
                                graphics.DrawString(base.Text, base.Font, Brushes.Black, TextPos.X, TextPos.Y);

                            break;
                    }
                }
            }

            protected override CreateParams CreateParams
            {
                get
                {
                    CreateParams result = base.CreateParams;
                    result.ExStyle |= 0x02000000; // WS_EX_COMPOSITED 
                    return result;
                }
            }
        }
```

The whole process of loading the messages from the hard disk seems very slow.
The files on the hard disk i read/load are type of eml some of the files size 8 KB and some 380 KB one is 4 MB

Answer (score 0):

What do you consider to be "very slow"?

Have you compared performance of a simple program that uses MimeKit to load all of the messages vs how long it takes your program with progress reporting?

Have you considered that perhaps your progress reporting is causing slowness? In general, you don't want to report progress after every small bit of work, you want to report it only when the progress has changed significantly.

If you are loading thousands of messages and you redraw your UI after every message, that's a lot of unnecessary re-rendering.

If that's still not fast enough, have you considered not loading all of the messages into memory? Why not load them only when you need them? The problem might be that you are loading so many messages into memory that it is causing your system to swap to disk.